# Do built-in operators participate in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I can't quite understand [over.built/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1). It says:

> The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators
> defined in [expr.compound] are specified in this subclause. These
> candidate functions **participate in the operator overload resolution**
> process as described in [over.match.oper] and are used for no other
> purpose.

But then, in the note, it says:

> Because built-in operators take only operands with non-class type, and
> **operator overload resolution occurs only when an operand expression
> originally has class or enumeration type**, operator overload resolution
> can resolve to a built-in operator only when an operand has a class
> type that has a user-defined conversion to a non-class type
> appropriate for the operator, or when an operand has an enumeration
> type that can be converted to a type appropriate for the operator.

I think it's a contradiction. So my question is does `1 + 1` involve the operator overload resolution or not?

Comment: No, by the note, but it's not a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. Suppose you have `a + 1`, where the type of `a` is a class that doesn't define its `operator +()`, but does define its `operator int()`. Then `a + 1` will use the built-in operator `+` to add two `int`s.

Comment: @heapunderrun the first quote says "These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution", but the second says "operator overload resolution occurs only when an operand expression originally has class or enumeration type". So in `1+1` plus is a candidate function. According to 1, it should participate in the operator overload resolution, according to 2 not. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot overload operations on built-in types, so in case of vanilla `1 + 1`, there's nothing to resolve.

Comment: @heapunderrun I agree that I can't overload them. But isn't it a candidate function according to https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#7? If it is, then why doesn't the first quote apply?

Comment: *X* can *participate in Y* only if *Y* takes place at all. The second highlighted sentence tells when *Y* takes place. And only then does the first highlighted sentence matter and *X can participate Y*.

Comment: @j6t but note that there's no "can", just "participate". And after all, if the first quote never applies (note that the first sentence specifically refers to built-in operators, not all operators), it means that these functions "are used for no other purpose", so it makes no sense to add the quote at all.

Comment: Why do you think it "_never applies_"? I've provided a simple sample case where it does apply.

Comment: @heapunderrun Ah, I think I get it now! "These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution" - here "these candidate functions" refer to only functions with class/enum operands that don't have overloaded operators, but can be converted to built-in types.

Comment: As I said, `a + 1` will resolve to the **built-in** addition of two `int`s if the type of `a` is a class that defines the conversion `operator int()`, but **does not** define an `operator +()`.

Comment: Why does it matter? This expression will invoke the built-in operator no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** In your first quoted statement, you've misread the last statement. In particular, you've only highlighted the part that says "*participate in the operator overload resolution*" instead of highlighting the whole part "*participate in the operator overload resolution process as described in [over.match.oper] and are used for no other purpose.*"

**This is important because** this means that to understand the behavior of `1+1` we've to look at *[over.match.oper]* as explained below.

---

> my question is does `1 + 1` involve the operator overload resolution or not?

Let's see what happens in this case `1+1` according to the standard.

**First**, as per [over.built#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1):

> These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process **as described in** [over.match.oper](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper) and are used for no other purpose. [over.match.oper] and are used for no other purpose.

Note the emphasis on "as described in [over.match.oper]". **This means that we have to next look/read** [over.match.oper](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper). Note that in your first quote, you did not correctly highlight the complete part of the last senetence. That is, you interpret the first quote as "participate in the operator overload resolution" instead of saying "participate in the operator overload resolution process as described in [over.match.oper]".

---

**Second**, from [over.match.oper](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper):

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the **operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to** [expr.compound](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound).

**This means that next we have to look/read** [expr.compound].

From [expr.compound](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.add-1):

> The additive operators + and - group left-to-right.
> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.
>
> ```
> additive-expression:
>     multiplicative-expression
>     additive-expression + multiplicative-expression
>     additive-expression - multiplicative-expression
> ```
>
> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral or unscoped enumeration type.
>
> **The result of the binary** `+ operator` **is the sum of the operands.**
> The result of the binary - operator is the difference resulting from the subtraction of the second operand from the first.

(emphasis mine)

This means that the result of `1+1` is the sum of the operands `1` and `1`. Note also that there is `T operator+(T);` [available](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#7) that will be used here.

Comment: The result of the expression is not so interesting here. The question is whether the expression involves the overload resolution or not. And the key misunderstanding was that I thought "These candidate functions" in the quote refer to all candidate functions no matter what. But actually they refer to only those candidate functions that have at least one class/enum in the operands (that is what the note tries to clarify). That's not the case in `1+1` according to your second point, so no OR here.

Comment: @cppbest Don't take notes given in the standard too seriously. They are non-normative. The key misunderstanding were 1) you were ignoring the *"as described in [over.match.oper]"* part from the first quoted reference and 2) you were focussing on a non-normative note while ignoring the normative reference from the first quoted.

Comment: @cppbest If you read my answer carefully you will notice that it explains/quotes *"If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to expr.compound."*, so again focus on the normative part of the standard. Additionally, the result of the expression part is for completeness.

Comment: @cppbest  Notes given in the standard can be removed at any time. Don't take them too seriously. Don't rely on them or at least don't make conclusions based on them when you have a normative reference  available, as in this case. That's all I'm saying. That is, if you think that a note doesn't make sense but other normative reference does, then it is "likely" that there is a problem in the note and not in the normative reference.